# Python If statements (or any statement) to compare two columns based on two conditions (integer numbers)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have two columns A and B with the sample data below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 3 |
| 140 | 4 |
| 110 | 1 |

Using Pandas(Python), I want to perform an If statement if two conditions are met:

- If any item in column A is >120 and any item in column B is more than 2 (Print or do something)
- The comparison should be row based. (i.e compare the 120 in row 1 Column A to 3 in row 1 column B)

any help please?

I tried using the if statement together with df.loc but when I am getting errors when I execute the statement:

Comment: What should be the result if you have this input? `df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [120, 140, 110], 'Column B': [1, 1, 2]})` With the chosen answer there will be a match, but I don't think it should as you want the logic row-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want at least one row that matches both conditions, then first combine the two conditions with `&`, then aggregate with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
if (df['Column A'].gt(120) & df['Column A'].gt(2)).any():
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean indexing:

```
>>> df['Column A'].gt(120) & df['Column B'].gt(2)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

>>> df[df['Column A'].gt(120) & df['Column B'].gt(2)]
   Column A  Column B
1       140         4
```

After that, you can apply your function on filtered rows.